# Создать функцию, которая принимает текст, разделённый переносами строк и возвращает новый текст, в котором каждая строка обернута в тег

Tags: javascript, html

По итогу функция должна выдать такой результат, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как её лучше реализовать.

С помощью template string

```
const text = `Some
simple multiline
text`;

console.log(wrapInParagraph(text)); // <p>Some</p>
// <p>simple multiline</p>
// <p>text</p>

const text2 = 'some\ntext';

console.log(wrapInParagraph(text2)); // <p>some</p>
// <p>text</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) можно разделить по переносу строки.

Далее с помощью [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) обернуть каждую строку в тег

в итоге объединить все в одну строку с помощью [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const text = `Some
simple multiline
text`;

function wrapInParagraph(string) {
  return string.split(/\n/).map(line => `<p>${line}</p>`).join('');
}

console.log(wrapInParagraph(text)); // <p>Some</p>
// <p>simple multiline</p>
// <p>text</p>

const text2 = 'some\ntext';

console.log(wrapInParagraph(text2)); // <p>some</p>
// <p>text</p>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь